# QLPreviewController with NSData?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a file stored on a server as `NSData`. I'm fetching the data from the server (No issue with this). Next, I'm trying `QLPreviewController` to present the file. I can't seem to figure out how to get this step to work.

I have implemented the QLPreviewController, set my datasource and delegate, and present the previewController modally. All that seems to be working, however, I can't seem to figure out how to properly implement `previewController:previewItemAtIndex:` using my NSData. Any suggestions/examples?

Comment: You need to write to a file and then return the file's URL back.  That was how I used it.

Answer (score 2):

QLPreviewController only works with file urls. :(

> @property (readonly) NSURL *previewItemURL;
>
> The value of this property must be a file-type URL.